# Change and Auto delete expired MySQL records for Rails with script

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

Good day,

Im Making a timetable Rails app which displays data from a MySQL Table

This App Displays all the records in the DB and each record has a start and stop datetime field. Also the app will have a hidden "In Progress" image displayed with each record.

Im looking for a script that would be able to query the database table records and if the server time is passed the start time on a record but before the stop time it will then display the hidden image in the rails app.

Then Also once the Server time is passed the expired Start and Stop times of the records in the table. Those expired records will be auto removed from the Table

Below is what id like to achieve.

```
 If Server time < timetable.start and < timetable.stop then keep image hidden in rails

 If Server time > timetable.start but < timetable.stop display hidden image in rails

 If Server time > timetable.start and > timetable.stop remove data row from DB
```

Some Code

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @timetable.each do |timetable| %>
     <tr>
       <td class="start"><%= timetable.start %></td>
       <td class="stop"><%= timetable.stop %></td>
       <td class="sub"><%= timetable.subject %></td>
       <td class="paper"><%= timetable.paper %></td>
       <td class="progress"><%= image_tag("InProgress.gif", :alt => "In Progress") %>   ## This is the Hidden Image that only display once server time is passed the stop time
     </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would obviously need to also be able to set it to run periodically by itself.

I Apologise, I know My knowledge and skills with MySQL and Rails are quite limited and hope i've managed to describe it clearly. I hope someone is able to point me in the right direction or the best way of achieving this. Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you might want to look into the [mysql event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

Comment: Thank you, Will have a look.